# Develop into Laurent series around $0$: $\frac{e^{1/z}}{z - 3i} .$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Develop into Laurent series around $0$:

$$\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z - 3i} .$$

I was thinking of developing $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ first and then $\frac{1}{z - 3i}$, but I got stuck while writing its multiple as one sum. Is that a good way of solving this?
I'm new to developing to Laurent series so any hint helps!

Comment: $\dfrac1{z-3i}=\dfrac1{-3i+z}=\dfrac {i/3}{1+\dfrac 
 i3z}=\dfrac i3(1-\dfrac i3 z + \dfrac {-1}9z^2-\dfrac{-i}{27}z^3...=\dfrac i3 + \dfrac19z+\dfrac{-i}{27}z^2-\dfrac1{81}z^3...$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner there has been misunderstaning, I wanted to multipy Laurent's sum for $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ first and Laurent's sum for $\frac{1}{z - 3i}$ and that is where I got stuck with writing it down as one sum.

Comment: If you want to find the series associated with the product of both Laurent series, use the Cauchy Product (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two functions $f$ and $g$ holomorphic on an annulus $$\mathcal{A}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: r_0<|z-z_0|<r_1\},$$ then given Laurent series' $$f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n$$ and $$g(z)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_n (z-z_0)^n$$  valid on $\mathcal{A}$, we will have $fg$ hololomorphic on $\mathcal{A}$, as well, with Laurent series $$f(z)g(z)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n (z-z_0)^n, $$ where $$c_n=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_kb_{n-k},$$ valid on $\mathcal{A}.$ This is analogous to taking the product of two power series' with the same radius of convergence.